# A faster way to compute spatial transformation over batch and time dimension with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For a machine learning task, I have to compute a spatial transformation of 3D coordinates (rotation over z axis) for each frame in a time sequence. Moreover, I have a batch of these time series. I would like to reduce the use of for loops as much as possible.

Say I have a rotation matrix of shape (batch_size, 3, 3) and a tensor of shape (batch_size, seq_length, n_coordinates, 3). What I am currently doing is a double for loop over time and batch dimension, and computing the dot product for each 3D coordinates.

Here is the code :

```py
# Compute transformation
    for t in range(seq_length):
        for b in range(batch_size):
            X[b, t, :, :] = np.dot(rotation_z_matrix[b], X[b, t, :, :].T).T
```

I have looked at tensordot and einsum functions but in the end, I do not want to sum dot products over a dimension, I want to stack my dot products over 2 dimensions (batch and time).

Is there an efficient wait to write an equivalent code ?

Thanks' in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using broadcasting:

```
X@rotation_z_matrix.transpose(0,2,1)[:, None, ...]
```

This gives (on a mock dataset) the same answer as @Divakar's

```
batch_size = 10
seq_length = 8
n_coordinates = 12

X = np.random.randint(0,10,(batch_size, seq_length, n_coordinates, 3))
rotation_z_matrix = np.random.randint(0,10,(batch_size,3,3))

(X@rotation_z_matrix.transpose(0,2,1)[:, None, ...] == np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X)).all()
# True
```

But at least for this example it is considerably faster.

```
timeit(lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X, optimize=True), number=1000)
# 0.1285447319969535

timeit(lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X, optimize=False), number=1000)
# 0.07962286799738649

timeit(lambda: X@rotation_z_matrix.transpose(0,2,1)[:, None, ...], number=1000)
# 0.019039910010178573
```

Be sure to notice that setting the `optimize`flag actually slows `einsum` down. (This happens rather often to me.)

Update: The same example but with data converted to float dtype

```
timeit(lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X, optimize=True), number=1000)
# 0.12346570500812959
timeit(lambda: np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X, optimize=False), number=1000)
# 0.07575376800377853
timeit(lambda: X@rotation_z_matrix.transpose(0,2,1)[:, None, ...], number=1000)
# 0.027829282989841886
```

Comment: Nice! So, no point in jumping to einsum it seems for perf, hmm.

Comment: @Divakar It's pretty unpredictable, isn't it? Btw. what is your experience with `optimize`? Rather hit and miss, no?

Comment: Yes, `optimize` one I thought would work well for large axes that undergo sum-reductions. But doesn't seem to be the case, with newer NumPy versions at least. And if I remember correctly, the perf figures were comparable with matmul/@.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
X_new = np.einsum('ijk,ilmk->ilmj',rotation_z_matrix,X)
```

Also, play around with the `optimize` flag in `np.einsum` by setting it as `True` to use BLAS.